# Issue with bash script running from php as root

Tags: bash, shell-script, apt, dpkg

I'm making a php panel from which you can install apps like owncloud & plex on your server. I've created multiple bash scripts that install and remove software. I tested all of them from shell, everything works as it should. However, when I run the scripts from php as root using sudo on ubuntu 15.10, apt-get & dpkg are not working as they should.

In visudo I have:

```
seedbox ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/appinstaller
```

appinstaller is a bash script that run the install/uninstall apps bash scripts (e.g. appinstaller plex)

Plex script example:

```
dpkg --configure -a
cd /tmp
wget https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-media-server/0.9.15.6.1714-7be11e1/plexmediaserver_0.9.15.6.1714-7be11e1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i plexmediaserver_0.9.15.6.1714-7be11e1_amd64.deb
```

When I run appinstaller directly from bash everything works perfectly.

When I run appinstaller from php using (confirmed that script is running as root):

```
exec("sudo /bin/appinstaller plex > /home/installer.log 2>&1 &");
```

It works but I get apt & dpkg errors when I try to install other apps such as:

> E: The package plexmediaserver needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it. (even though it's installed and working)

And also `dpkg --configure -a` returns an error.

Plex is working fine, but seems like apt doesn't finish the installation process and gets stuck somewhere, also commands running after the `apt-get install`/`dpkg` won't run from php but will run from bash. I tried to run the script also from cron & systemctl and I get the same issue.

It's worth noting that some apps are installing/uninstalling without any issues.

What could be making the difference between running the script from php/cron/systemctl or from shell directly? Can I emulate normal bash session?

Comment: Is your "php panel" a web interface which you access via your browser?

Comment: Hi Dimitry yes it's a php web panel

Comment: Did you try `shell_exec` instead of `exec` ?

Comment: I tried now shell_exec, same issue, plex was installed and seem to work properly, but then when I try to install another app I get: E: The package plexmediaserver needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it. And apt-get stops.

Comment: @the_velour_fog Differences between [`shell_exec` and `exec`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec) seem to be insignificant for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Running PHP scripts as root is a dangerous practice. Web servers do their best to prevent privilege escalation, and implement various measures such as [chroot jail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). I believe that may be the cause of your problems.

In particular, `dpkg` needs to access files in `/var/lib/dpkg/` to be able to function properly. You can check whether you have access to this directory from your PHP scripts, e.g. by trying to list files in it, or read from `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. If you don't (even when running as root), then you're indeed in a jail. You can of course just disable the jail (how to do it depends on the web server), but I wouldn't recommend it. There is a reason why it was implemented, and circumventing security mechanisms exposes you to all sorts of attacks.

Comment: I'm aware of the risk, and I'm willing to take it. I've tested and I can access these files from the bash script, so not in jail.